# Failure while pushing vhd to Azure container registry using oras push

Tags: azure, azure-artifacts, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to push a 9gb vhd file as oci image to Azure container registry. For a vhd of size 500mb, it succeeded.

But the 9gb vhd is failing with the following error:

*Preparing simplvmvhd1.vhd
Uploading 2fff39d3fd1a simplvmvhd1.vhd
time="2022-06-01T13:48:03+05:30" level=warning msg="reference for unknown type: application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+vhd" digest="sha256:2fff39d3fd1a01c5fb6287dc5f62e08b87f78ef32da0f5264821cd8b30e7f4c4" mediatype=application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+vhd size=10000269824
time="2022-06-01T13:48:03+05:30" level=warning msg="reference for unknown type: application/vnd.unknown.config.v1+json" digest="sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855" mediatype=application/vnd.unknown.config.v1+json size=0
Error: failed to copy: failed to do request: Put "https://somahantaregistry.azurecr.io/v2/images/simplvmimage/blobs/uploads/abe27346-0d69-47e1-a1c8-70dbe333f330?_nouploadcache=false&_state=Vqc1yNiwQYK6wLnHb6T2cxv6hgcWpUupp6n-QrWDbeF7Ik5hbWUiOiJpbWFnZXMvc2ltcGx2bWltYWdlIiwiVVVJRCI6ImFiZTI3MzQ2LTBkNjktNDdlMS1hMWM4LTcwZGJlMzMzZjMzMCIsIk9mZnNldCI6MCwiU3RhcnRlZEF0IjoiMjAyMi0wNi0wMVQwODoxODoxNC4zMTIwOTIzNTFaIn0%3D&digest=sha256%3A2fff39d3fd1a01c5fb6287dc5f62e08b87f78ef32da0f5264821cd8b30e7f4c4": write tcp 192.168.29.71:59978->52.168.114.2:443: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.*

Sometimes this error:
*write tcp 192.168.29.71:51899->52.168.114.2:443: wsasend: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

Can someone help me understand this error and how to complete the upload?

Answer (score 1):

The error cannot be reproduced from our side. ACR doesn't have a size limit when using oras push. The current size limit in ACR is about 500G per request.